# SELECT all substrings (n-grams) of length n?

Tags: postgresql

How could I select all *n-grams*, ie. substrings of length *n* from a string using SQL? For example, the 3-grams of string *example* are *exa*, *xam*, *amp*, *mpl*, *ple*.

I'm using PostgreSQL to be more precise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('example' FROM n FOR 3) 
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, LENGTH( 'example' )-2, 1) n;
exa
xam
amp
mpl
ple
```

Here it is in a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ngrams(varchar, integer) RETURNS SETOF TEXT AS $$
SELECT SUBSTRING($1 FROM n FOR $2)::TEXT
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, LENGTH($1)-($2-1), 1) n;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Use it like:

```
SELECT ngrams('example', 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a module in PostgreSQL which supports trigrams (not n-grams). it is called `pg_trgm`.

Do the following:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

then ...

```
SELECT show_trgm('hello');
```

The result will be

```
 {"  h"," he",ell,hel,llo,"lo "}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
DECLARE @str varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @ngram int 
DECLARE @i int 

SET @i = 1
SET @ngram = 5 
SET @str = 'Helloworldsed'

WHILE (@i <= (len(@str)-@ngram)+1)
BEGIN
SELECT SUBSTRING(@str,@i,@ngram)
SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Comment: That is invalid SQL for Postgres

Comment: just change syntax, like while loop  end loop